# Не применяется декоратор @observable

Tags: javascript, babel, mobx

Пытаюсь написать store для mobx. Простейший пример:

```
class AppStore {
    @observable lock;

    constructor() {
        this.lock = false;
    }

    @action('toggle lock')
        toggleLock() {
        this.lock = !this.lock;
    }

    @computed get isLocked() {
        return this.lock;
    }
}

const appStore = new AppStore();
```

после обработки babel-cli c параметрами

```
--plugins transform-class-properties,transform-decorators-legacy
--source-maps 
--no-comments 
--stage 0 
--presets=react,es2015
```

декоратор @observable не применяется. Никаких ошибок не выдается. Применение декоратора "в лоб":

```
extendObservable(this, {
    lock: false
});
```

срабатывает. Самое интересное, что декораторы @action и @computed применились без проблем.

Что я забыл указать/настроить?

в бандл подключаются:

```
global.observable = require('mobx').observable;
global.computed = require('mobx').computed;
global.action = require('mobx').action;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ заключен в пропущенной по невнимательности строчке документации (https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html):

> Note that the order of plugins is important: transform-decorators-legacy should be listed first.

Имеет значение порядок указания плагинов. Плагин "transform-decorators-legacy" должен быть первым в списке. После изменения порядка все заработало